# How to make a XStream tag Optional using annotations

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xstream

How do I make an @XStreamImplicit annotated tag `Optional`.

I have 2 classes :
Class2 object is declared in Class1

```
@XStreamAlias("root")
public class Class1 {
  @XStreamAlias("tag1")
  private String data1;
  @XStreamAlias("class2")
  private Class2 data2;
}


@XStreamAlias("class2")
public class Class2 {
  @XStreamAlias("tag2child1")
  private String dataInChild1;
  @XStreamAlias("tag2child2")
  private String dataInChild2;
}
```

The Xml looks like this

```
<root>
  <tag1>data</tag1>
  <class2>
    <tag2child1>dataInChild1</tag2child1>
    <tag2child2>dataInChild2</tag2child2>
  </class2>
</root>
```

If the tag `<class2>` is not present in the xml, its fine.
But if its present in the xml, i'll take the data.

Comment: In your example here is no necessary for @XStreamImplicit, can you explain what you want to arrive?